# $wpdb->prepare returns empty array

Tags: database, wpdb

For some reason the query in this function returns an empty array. I have been looking at this for far too long now and can't figure out why. Does anybody have an idea? Do i use $wpdb->prepare correctly?

```
function getComponents($page_id, $currentLanguage) {
       global $wpdb;
       $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
          'SELECT id, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_name, m1.meta_value AS `template`, m2.meta_value AS `home_description` ' .
          'FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' p ' .
          'JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON p.ID=r.object_id ' .
          'JOIN wp_terms t ON r.term_taxonomy_id=t.term_id ' .
          'WHERE t.slug=%s AND post_parent=%d AND post_type="page" AND post_status="publish"' .
          'ORDER BY menu_order ASC ',
          $currentLanguage, $page_id
       ), OBJECT_K);
       return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
function getComponents($page_id, $currentLanguage) {
       global $wpdb;
       $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "
          SELECT id, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_name, m1.meta_value AS 'template', m2.meta_value AS 'home_description'
          FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
          JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON p.ID = r.object_id
          JOIN wp_terms t ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
          WHERE t.slug=%s AND post_parent = %d AND post_type='page' AND post_status = 'publish'
          ORDER BY menu_order ASC ",
          $currentLanguage, $page_id ), OBJECT_K );
       return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Pure code dumps are not recommended. Please explain why this solves the problem, thanks.